# Can not find the tag library descriptor for tiles when using Maven

Tags: jsp, maven, struts2, apache-tiles

Here is my config in `web.xml` file

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Here is the config in `pom.xml`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

It keeps saying this: `Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://struts.apache.org/tags-tiles"` when I add taglib into layout:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="tiles" uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-tiles"%>
```

And when I run on server:

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener
```

Did I miss something here?

Comment: Perhaps you have the same problem listed in http://struts.1045723.n5.nabble.com/ClassNotFoundException-StrutsTilesListener-td3553672.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [Kenny Lee](http://kennii.wordpress.com/2010/01/28/debuging-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-context-contextloaderlistener-in-eclipse-tomcat-maven/#comments) I found out the solution for this one after weeks :((
You’ll need to configure your eclipse project settings by:

1. Right click on the project in eclipse on the left panel under the package explorer view.
2. Click Java EE Module Dependencies.
3. Check (make sure the checkbox is ticked) the Maven Dependencies option (the last option).

For Eclipse 3.6 [Click Here for more information](http://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/eclipse-java-ee-module-dependencies-is-replaced-by-web-deployment-assembly/)

Sometimes after configuration you have to refresh the project or use `mvn clean` and `mvn install` and it will do the tricks

Answer (score 0):

your web.xml is missing the taglib declaration:

```
<taglib>
  <taglib-uri>
    http://struts.apache.org/tags-tiles
  </taglib-uri>
  <taglib-location>
    /WEB-INF/tags-tiles.tld
  </taglib-location>
</taglib>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I use Tiles definitions defined in a centralized file. :(

Answer (score 0):

How about using the dependency versions as specified in [this example](http://www.vaannila.com/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-tiles-example-1.html) to see if it works?

As [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013078/problem-in-configuration-project-using-struts-tiles-maven/6013218#6013218) in your [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013078/problem-in-configuration-project-using-struts-tiles-maven), it looks like `struts2-tiles` dependency is required and maybe you do not need `struts2-spring-plugin`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, as you can see in my related question, after I added struts2-tiles-plugin, I still got `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener` :(